# Select 2 different set of columns from column multiindex dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, slice, multi-index

I have the following column multiindex dataframe.

[image]

I would like to select (or get a subset) of the dataframe with different columns of each level_0 index (i.e. x_mm and y_mm from virtual and z_mm rx_deg ry_deg rz_deg from actual). From what I have read I think I might be able to use pandas [IndexSlice](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.IndexSlice.html#pandas.IndexSlice) but not entire sure how to use it in this context.

So far my work around is to use `pd.concat` selecting the 2 sets of columns independently. I have the feeling that this can be done neatly with slicing.

Comment: Can you provide a reproducible input instead of your image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can programmatically generate the tuples to slice your MultiIndex:

```
from itertools import product

cols = ((('virtual',), ('x_mm', 'y_mm')),
        (('actual',),  ('z_mm', 'rx_deg', 'ry_deg', 'rz_deg'))
 )

out = df[[t for x in cols for t in product(*x)]]
```